# get COUNT to return 0 when EXISTS() subquery is false

Tags: sql

Given the following query:

```
SELECT M.year, COUNT(C.eid)
  FROM Card AS C, Month AS M
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Charge AS CH
               WHERE CH.usingcard=C.eid AND CH.year=M.year)
  GROUP BY M.year
```

where EXISTS is used to avoid the number of 'Charge' matching the given year/card changing the count. The pb is that I would like a resulting row for each possible 'Month' row, eg when there are no matching 'Charge', I would like to get 0 as count, while I currently get no row at all.

Without EXISTS, I could use an outer join. I could also probably use an UNION with a query returning 0 for case where NOT EXISTS().

Anyone has a smarter idea ?

Comment: Your `UNION` suggestion would certainly work (as would an `OUTER JOIN`, noting it is merely a special case of `UNION`). So what do you mean by "smarter"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This avoids the the problem of multiple Charge records:

```
SELECT M.year, COUNT(distinct CH.usingcard)
FROM Card AS C
CROSS JOIN Month AS M
LEFT JOIN Charge CH on CH.usingcard=C.eid AND CH.year=M.year
GROUP BY M.year
```

This counts how may *different* cards were charged in the year. Non-joining rows will have `CH.usingcard` of null, which won't be counted.

Comment: I still get a empty set rather than a row showing a zero count (it also generates an error on SQL Server, The multi-part identifier "C.eid" could not be bound.)

Comment: Sorry - I left out the `LEFT` - try it now. Re C.eid: Give me a break... I took that from YOUR question. You didn't post the schema, so we must guess. You need to replace C.eid with whatever column is the joining column to the "charge" table.

Comment: You've mistaken me for the one asking the question when I'm merely peer reviewing answers ;)

Comment: FWIW still errors on SQL Server (unless you use `CROSS JOIN` in place of the comma in the `FRON` clause; `C.eid` is the correct column to use, as posted) even though the syntax looks OK. Now returning the correct result as far as I can tell :)

Comment: I wasn't sure if your server supported CROSS JOIN cos you didn't say which one you use. I put it in. thx 4 feedback

Comment: again, you've mistaken me for the OP. The person asking the question is @sthenault. But changing to `CROSS JOIN` could be a good thing anyhow :)

Answer (score 1):

The NOT EXISTS is excluding zero counts: as expected

If you want zero counts, then you need the OUTER JOIN. However, your FROM clause is a CROSS JOIN so you'd get wrong counts. And you can ignore the Card table because usingcard has the same data (otherwise you wouldn't use it in your EXISTS)

It is this simple...

```
SELECT
    M.year, COUNT(CH.usingcard)
FROM
    Month AS M
    LEFT JOIN
    Charge AS CH On CH.year = M.year
GROUP BY
    M.year
```

Comment: "And you can ignore the Card table" -- Can you explain your leap of logic, please?

Comment: @onedaywhen: Why join when CH.usingcard=C.eid? You have all the info you need in CH.usingcard. Unless OP wants all card/month combinations then a JOIN... but then you are grouping by Month so using Card still adds no value. Feel free to *contribute* rather than *criticise*...

Comment: @onedaywhen: The OP's original question doesn't need *two* tables, because what it essentially does is counting cards that exist in `Charge` for every year that exists in `Charge`. Now, the OP has expressed a wish to account for *all possible* years, meaning years that are represented in the `Month` table. Therefore you need to use left join like in @gbn's answer.

Comment: @gbn: I made up some sample data then compared the results of the OP's code against your code and they are different (peer review, that's my contribution here :) Hardly surprising when you omit a table that appears in the `FROM` clause of the main query! Why does the fact a two tables can be joined (e.g. being generous, have common attributes but could merely be compatible data types!) mean that they have the same data. The fact they've used semiijoin (`EXISTS`) rather than inner join (and the wording of the question) indicates they data is not the same.

Comment: @gbn: see my comment (=contribution) to the question ;)

Comment: @Andriy M: "need to use a left join"? So a right outer join is completely out of the question, then? ;) Consider that an outer join is merely a special case of a union, both of which were name-checked by the OP but asked for a *smarter* answer.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I wouldn't like to discriminate right or full join, but 'left join' is what first springs to my mind when talking about outer joins. But you are right, I should have said 'outer join', because that was what I meant.

Answer (score -1):

If all arguments are NULL, COALESCE returns NULL.

```
COALESCE(expression1,...n) is equivalent to the following CASE expression:

CASE

   WHEN (expression1 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression1

   WHEN (expression2 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression2

   ...

   ELSE expressionN

END
```

The following example shows how COALESCE selects the data from the first column that has a nonnull value.

```
SELECT Name, Class, Color, ProductNumber,
COALESCE(Class, Color, ProductNumber) AS FirstNotNull
FROM Production.Product ;
```

Comment: How does your answer relate to the question?

Answer (score -1):

You could the NULLIF function which can be used inside the count function. This function takes two parameters: if the parameters are equal, then it returns null, else it returns the value of the first parameter.

```
SELECT M.year, COUNT (NULLIF (CH.usingcard, NULL))
FROM Month as M left join Charge as CH
ON CH.Year = M.Year
GROUP BY M.year
```

Comment: When the second parameter to `NULLIF()` is `NULL` then it will have no effect.

Comment: @Onedaywhen: Exactly - nulls won't be counted. The OP stated that he wanted to see 0 for months (years) where there is no use. Using a 'normal' count and a left join will always give a count of at least 1.

Comment: Think it through: "if the parameters are equal". In the case when `CH.usingcard` is `NULL`, it will return `NULL`. When `CH.usingcard` is not `NULL`, it will return `CH.usingcard`. The result in both cases is the same as `CH.usingcard`, so `NULLIF()` is having no effect. The same applies to every case when the second parameter is `NULL`. "if the parameters are equal" -- tell me, when in SQL does `NULL = NULL` evaluate TRUE?

Comment: But, worse, the net effect of your query is to count even when the OP's subquery is FALSE!